# Why does inspect compile:packageWar::packagedArtifact fail in the Sbt console when using xsbt-web-plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I am using xsbt-web-plugin with Sbt 0.13.2.  If I add the following to build.sbt I can type "myTask" in the console and it works:

```
val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("My task.")

myTask :=  {
  val (art, file) = packagedArtifact.in(Compile, packageWar).value
  println("Artifact definition: " + art)
  println("Packaged file: " + file.getAbsolutePath)
}
```

But why does this return an error if I type it in the Sbt console?

```
inspect compile:packageWar::packagedArtifact
```

Error message:

```
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: packageWar (similar: package, packageSrc, package-src)
[error] inspect compile:packageWar::packagedArtifact
[error]                           ^
```

For comparison, this one does work:

```
inspect compile:packageBin::packagedArtifact
```

Key parts of build.sbt:

```
tomcat()

name := "my-war"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

webappSrc in webapp := baseDirectory.value / "web"

webInfClasses in webapp := true

val myTask = taskKey[Unit]("My task.")

myTask :=  {
  val (art, file) = packagedArtifact.in(Compile, packageWar).value
  println("Artifact definition: " + art)
  println("Packaged file: " + file.getAbsolutePath)
}
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "1.0.0-M4")
```

(I'm only asking so that I can understand Sbt better, it's not actually causing a problem.)

Comment: Can you print the error message? What's inside `build.sbt` is scoped to the project the build file is in so it may contribute to what you experience...somehow.

Comment: do you have `warSettings` in your build file?

Comment: I have added the requested information.  I have also tried adding warSettings to build.sbt, I did not see any changes as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this info from `package` rather than `packageWar`:

```
> inspect compile:package::packagedArtifact
[info] Task: scala.Tuple2[sbt.Artifact, java.io.File]
[info] Description:
[info]  Generates a packaged artifact, returning the Artifact and the produced File.
```

The `packageWar` task is [set up indirectly](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/b9fc19660c7bd934dac3692758e006b71d932428/src/main/scala/war.scala#L11) using [`packageTaskSettings`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/sxr/sbt/Defaults.scala.html#sbt.Defaults.packageTaskSettings).

Comment: Thanks, I now see the scala variable is named packageWar, but the name it is given is "package".  And the war stuff seems to be in global scope *:package, while the original jar stuff stays in compile:packageBin.